# Reason for 'collection#find: pass a function instead, Tags.create is not a function'

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, discord.js

I am setting up a Discord bot, and I am making a warn command in which all the entries will be logged inside of a `Sequelize` table. Currently, I am also using a main `index.js`, and have a folder that has all the commands. `index.js` calls each command when the bot starts. I'm using https://discordjs.guide/ for help and guidance. I used their `Seqeulize` database help, so I'm "adding a tag" and I put exactly what they said to put, except my own column names.

I haven't tried anything because I don't know any idea why this might be happening. I am just starting in JS and self-taught, so I don't know much.

```js
const Tags = sequelize.define('moderation', {
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: false,
  },
  case_num: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    unique: true,
  },
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  reason: Sequelize.STRING,
  length: Sequelize.STRING,
  by: { 
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: false,
  },
  date: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
  }
});
```

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const {parseUser} = require('../util/parseUser.js');
const {caseNumber} = require('../util/caseNumber.js');
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const Tags = require ('../modTable.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    operatorsAliases: false,
    // SQLite only
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
  });
    if(!message.member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS'])) 
      return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");


    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user === message.author) {
        return message.channel.send('You cannot do that to yourself, why did you try?');
    }
    const modlogs = bot.channels.find('name', 'mod-logs');
    const caseNum = await caseNumber(bot, modlogs);
    if (!modlogs) return message.reply('I cannot find a mod-log channel');
    if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) return message.reply('You must mention someone to warn them.').catch(console.error);
    const reason = args.splice(1, args.length).join(' ') || `no reason provided`;
    let date = new Date();
    const type_warn = "warn";

    try {
      const tag = await Tags.create({
        username: message.mentions.users.first(),
        case_num: caseNum,
        type: type_warn,
        reason: reason,
        length: null,
        by: message.author.username,
        date: date,
      });
      console.log(e);
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return message.reply('Something went wrong with adding this warn to the table. Please contact Charlee or VorTex eXDee!');
    }
```

I expect the thing to be logged and no error to come up on the terminal, but it says:

> `Deprecationwarning: collection#find: pass a function instead`
>
> `TypeError: Tags.create is not a function.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Collection#find: pass a function instead`

[`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) can take a function instead of a property and value. The latter use is deprecated.

**Solution:**

```js
Collection.find(element => element.property === value)
```

*(You can compare properties other ways too, and multiple at once.)*

---

> `Tags.create() is not a function`

When you require `modTable.js`, you're declaring `Tags` as the file's `module.exports` property. You can assign values to and create properties for `module.exports` so you can access your variables elsewhere.

**Solution:**

Export the variable from the file.

```js
module.exports = Tags;
// You can also use: module.exports.Tags = Tags;
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. module.exports didn't work. still had the same problem. And where am I supposed to put in the first solution? thanks so much for your time! :)

Comment: Log `Tags` after you require the the modTable file. If it's present, you're using `module.exports` correctly, but the origin of the problem must be the actual code. Change `Collection.find()` wherever you're using the deprecated version, i.e. `message.member.roles.find(...)` or `guild.channels.find(...)`.